# Question About Bernoulli's Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In Bernoulli's equation, should the pressure variable be gauge pressure, atmospheric pressure, or absolute pressure?

Comment: What do you mean by absolute pressure?

Comment: Is it a combination of both gauge and atmospheric pressure?

Comment: I think gauge pressure is pressure measured relative to the atmospheric pressure. So both leads to redundancy.

Comment: @sslucifer - depending on the specific gauge, 'gauge pressure' may be relative to standard atmospheric pressure, or to actual local pressure. Those of us living reasonably above sea level need to check what we order...

Comment: It's your choice.  Also, it's easy enough to reformulate the Bernoulli equation such that it calculates $\Delta P (e.g., P2 - P1)$, which totally eliminates the need to worry about how pressure is measured, because only differences in pressure matter with that formulation.

Answer (score -1):

In general $P$ in Bernoulli equation is the total pressure other than created by gravitational force and kinetic energy of the fluid. So for simple system, we generally take it to be atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score -1):

$P$ is the local pressure. If an equation of state is given, such as the ideal gas equation of state, then we can understand $P$ as being given by local density and temperature.

The atmospheric pressure comes in as boundary condition when integrating the Bernoulli equation vertically. Absolute pressure is just a vocabulary for the local pressure + $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$, locally and this can also be integrated globally.
Gauge pressures are always differences in local, absolute pressure integrated between two points.